# No. of Threads in a Intel i5 processor

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads

How many Threads should I run on my Intel i5 processor to get maximum utilization. I understand that on running to much thread i won't get any advantage since they will keep waiting in Waiting Queue. So what is the Optimal Number of Thread ?

Comment: That probably depends on what type of work the threads are doing, i.e, if your code is I/O or CPU intensive, etc.

Comment: what you should to do is to write the application and test it varying the number of threads

Answer (score 2):

For compute-intensive workloads you may like to utilize all available CPUs, including Hyper-Threaded cores.

And benchmark how your workloads scale depending on the number of CPUs utilized.